# Combine values but with no duplicate values for a given compound id

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I've got this table:

```
id1  category    id2
1    13          a
1    13          b
1    13          c
2    183         d
2    183         e
3    13          a
3    13          b
3    13          c
4    183         d
4    183         e
5    13          a
5    13          b
5    13          c
```

I'd like to get as result a combination of unique `id1 and category` associated with values of `id2` without duplicates. It doesn't matter what row gets picked, as long these conditions are met.

Valid output:

```
id1  category    id2
1    13          a
2    183         d
3    13          b
4    183         e
5    13          c
```

id1 1 must always appear with category 13, and for that pair I want to pick a value of id2 between a, b and c. But once I have choosen one, the other pairs of (id1,  category) can't pick that same value for id2.

Comment: That's actually a *hard* problem, then. You want `UNIQUE(id1, category)` and `UNIQUE(id2)` while including *all* distinct combinations of `(id1, category)`. May not even be possible. If the same `id2` is associated to two different combinations of `(id1, category)` (and no other `id2` is), you have to break one condition or the other.

Comment: Provide your version of Postgres and basics about your data distribution. How many rows, how many distinct combinations of `(id1, category)`, how many distinct `id2` for each? Your example suggests certain patterns in the distribution of `id2` values. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id1, category) t.*
from t
order by id1, category;
```

Hmmm.  You perhaps mean that `id2` should not be duplicated -- the question is hard to follow.  If so, this would be:

```
select distinct on (id2) t.*
from t
order by id2;
```

EDIT:

Your problem is much more complicated than it first sounds.  You can accomplish this with a recursive subquery.  The following works on the data that you have provided:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, category, id2,
             array[(id, category, id2)] as all_three,
             array[(id, category)] as idcategories, array[id2] as id2s, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select t.id, t.category, t.id2, all_three || (t.id, t.category, t.id2), 
             cte.idcategories || (t.id, t.category), cte.id2s || t.id2,
             lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on  (t.id, t.category) <> all (cte.idcategories) and
             t.id2 <> all (cte.id2s)
      where lev < 7
     )
select u.*
from (select cte.*
      from cte
      order by lev desc
      limit 1
     ) x cross join lateral
     unnest(x.all_three) as u(id int, category int, id2 varchar(50));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=68b334b8a3b0b0025419b3d2a7a2916b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The question was clarified, so that the answer is now off target.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easier to express if each row is uniquely identified, as that does not exist in the sample table (which I'm calling t1), the first step is to create such a table.

After that, we use recursion, where the base steps are that `id1 = 1, category = 13 & id2 IN (a, b, c)`. We introduce three dummy columns to keep track of which id2 values have been seen, which id1-category values have been seen and which rows have been visited.

In each recursive steps we join a row if the id1-category (the compound primary key) & id2 have not been seen yet.

After the recursive step, we select the row number array (rns) of the sequence terminators. This is identified through checking that (any of) the dummy variable array lengths equals the number of distinct id1-category values in t1. We are picking a random solution here.

The final query just picks out the set of rows identified in the `random_solution`
step.

```
WITH RECURSIVE numbered_t1 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
  FROM t1
)
, rec AS (
  SELECT 
    id1
  , category 
  , id2
  , ARRAY[id2] seen2
  , ARRAY[rn] rns
  , ARRAY[(id1, category)] seen1
  FROM numbered_t1
  WHERE (id1, category) = (1, 13) 
    AND id2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c')        
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    t.id1
  , t.category
  , t.id2
  , rec.seen2 || t.id2
  , rec.rns || t.rn
  , rec.seen1 || (t.id1, t.category)
  FROM numbered_t1 t
  JOIN rec 
    ON (t.id1, t.category) != ALL(rec.seen1) 
   AND t.id2 != ALL(rec.seen2)
 )
, random_solution AS (
  SELECT rns
  FROM rec
  WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(seen1, 1) IN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (id1, category)) FROM t1)
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT id1, category, id2 
FROM numbered_t1
JOIN random_solution 
  ON rn = ANY(rns)
```